# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder

Tags: java

I am working on a REST service and trying to get JSON from it. I use WildFly and when I run client this error appears. I have added some dependencies but couldn't solve it.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXBEO.png)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.metehan</groupId>
    <artifactId>restsetup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restsetup</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.json/jakarta.json-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[JsonClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbQyS.png)

I solved it. Removed all dependencies and add this. I don't know why it showed me error, only one dependency worked. Does resteasy-client dependency includes others ?

```
<dependency>             
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>             
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.Final</version>         
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to convery textual information like code and exception stacktraces. Post them as code formatted text. If the system prompts you that a question is mostly code, then you should either provide **more** explanation about your problem, or **reduce** the code to the absolute minimum necessary (a [mre]). For example, you haven't even specified the version of WildFly you're using, and you could reduce the XML to only show the dependencies. Probably you need to declare that your project uses the appropriate module in the deployment descriptor of WildFly.

Comment: Okay i will examine it. I have added code but system keep saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." so then i added it as screenshot because of i thought system will accept it. Sorry about it, i am new. Thanks for reply